# manually set zoom / rotate using orbit control

Tags: three.js

I am working on a project which is using `three.js`, it consists of a room having a few items. I have to rotate and zoom the room and for this I used `orbitControl.js`.

I am facing an issue in which I am not able to rotate my room properly. I want to rotate the room by 90 degrees so that I can see it from different views like
left, right, top & bottom views.

I used the below code:

```
this.customRotate = function(angle) {
    constraint.rotateLeft(angle);
    scope.update();
};

this.rotateLeft = function(angle) {
    thetaDelta -= angle;
};
```

but when I provide angle `math.pi /2`, the first time it rotates the view by 90 degrees but if I call the function again it rotates with less accuracy and so on if I further call the function like `controls.customRotate(Math.PI/2)`